# Create .htaccess Wildcard with Subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, wildcard

I'm trying to implement a solution using .htaccess and wildcard subdomains so that

http://example.com.domain.com is mapped to http://domain.com/www/example.com

. My rules look something like:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www.)?([a-z0-9-\.]+)\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^www/ www/%2%{REQUEST_URI} [PT,L]
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: show to index page but i need show to http://domain.com/www/example.com

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the second rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule !^www/ index.php [L]
```